# How to combine meta_query and orderby date meta in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, date, sql-order-by

I have 3 meta fields, date (date formatted string), location, and consultant.

I can pull the posts and orderby the date field when meta_key is set:

```
// get posts
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type'     => 'event',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'meta_key'      => 'start_date',
    'orderby'       => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'         => 'DESC'
));
```

However, I have not be able to get this to work with a more complex `meta_query`:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'uppy_events',
    'orderby'       => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'         => 'ASC',

    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => $key,
            'value' => array($value),
            'compare' => '>='
            )
        ),
        'numberposts' => -1
    );
```

Basically I want to pull all posts that have a meta `start_date` greater than today's date and order by these dates.

As a side note - can you do a `meta_query` search on say location key and still orderby date key?

This is the first time I've ever tried ordering by meta, and have found some good posts but still cannot wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I figured this out as my post lead me to another good example. The commented out `meta_query` is date greater than today. The other is using a different key. Both work!

```
    $today = date("Ymd");
    
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'uppy_events',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'meta_key' => 'event_date', 
        'orderby'       => 'meta_value_num',
        'order'         => 'ASC',
        'meta_query' => array(
            /* array(
                'key' => 'event_date',
                'value' => $today,
                'compare' => '>='
            ) */
            array(
                'key' => 'event_location',
                'value' => 'vancouver',
                'compare' => '='
            )
        ),
        'numberposts' => -1
    );
```